# createStore function returns undefined store object

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am very new to React Native and in the process of creating some sample apps. So following a tutorial app, i was trying to create a Taxi Booking App that has redux store involved in it.

So my App.js file looks as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Root from "./src/main";
export default class TaxiApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Root {...this.props}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The main.js file is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import createStore from "./store/createStore";
import AppContainer from "./AppContainer";

export default class Root extends React.Component{
    renderApp(){
        const initialState = window.___INITIAL_STATE__;
        const store = createStore(initialState);

        return(
            <AppContainer store={store}/>
        );
    }
    render(){
        return this.renderApp();

    }
}
```

The AppContainer component is as follows:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";
import {Router} from "react-native-router-flux";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import scenes from "../routes/scenes";

export default class AppContainer extends Component{
    static propTypes = {
        store : PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Provider store={this.props.store}>
                <Router scenes={scenes}/>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

The createStore() function for the Root component is as follows:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import makeRootReducer from "./reducers";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import  createSocketIoMiddleware  from "redux-socket.io";

import io from "socket.io-client/dist/socket.io";

let socket = io("http://localhost:3000", {jsonp:false});

let socketIoMiddleware = createSocketIoMiddleware(socket, "server/");

const log =  createLogger({ diff: true, collapsed: true });

// a function which can create our store and auto-persist the data
export default (initialState = {}) => {

    // ======================================================
    // Middleware Configuration
    // ======================================================
    const middleware = [thunk, log, socketIoMiddleware];

    // ======================================================
    // Store Enhancers
    // ======================================================
    const enhancers = [];

    // ======================================================
    // Store Instantiation
    // ======================================================
    const store = createStore(
        makeRootReducer(),
        initialState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(...middleware),
            ...enhancers
        )
    );
    return store;
};
```

On trying to run this in the android emulator I am getting the following error:

> undefined is not an object(evaluating '_react.PropTypes.object')

It would be great if someone could help. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you add all the import lines to your code snippets, especially the ones for the AppContainer?

Comment: have you installed prop-types package ??

Comment: @Chris: I have added the import lines too in the code snipets. Could you please check it now

Comment: @Joseph : It has been installed. I have imported this in the AppContainer.js file

Comment: The error is pointing to PropTypes as the root of the issue; `import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";` means you're trying to use the deprecated version. It's its own package now, try `import PropTypes from "prop-types";` instead.

Comment: @ChrisG: Thanks..this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

remove import proptypes from the react package